# Java-Buffered Reader, How do you read a line using br.readLine(System.in) and convert it to char?

Tags: java, string

I have to do a cryptography program in Java which takes a number and a string(as an instance variable) from the user and adds that number to the ASCII of each letter in the string to create a new String.For example, if the number is 2 and the original string is "ABCXYZ" it should print "CDEZAB"
This is what I've got so far:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Program12 {

   String str;

   public void encodeDecode() throws IOException

   {

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      System.out.println("Input a string");

      str = br.readLine();

      System.out.println("input a number");
      **char a=char.parseChar(br.readLine(System.in));**
      String ustr = str.toUpperCase();
      int l = ustr.length();
      for (int x = 0; x < l; ++x) {
         char t = ustr.charAt(x);
         if (('t' + a) > 90) {
            char c = 90 - 't';
            char p = c - a;
            char d = 65 + p;
            System.out.print(d);
         } else {
            System.out.print('t' + a);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

but it keeps on saying there is a mistake in the conversion of String to char.how do i fix it?

Comment: Have you tried the `br.read()` method? it reads from the input stream character by character. and you can check for when the buffer is empty using `while(br.read()!=-1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were many things to suggest so i have modified your code completely according to your requirement if you dont understand anything you can ask me

```
public class Program12 {

   String str,newStr="";  
   int num;

   public void encodeDecode() throws IOException

   {

     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

          System.out.println("Input a string");

          str = br.readLine();
          str.toUpperCase();
          System.out.println("input a number");

          num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
          char ch;int sum;
          for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
          {
              ch=str.charAt(i);
              if((ch+num)>90)
              {
                  sum=((ch+num)%90%26);
                  if(sum>0)
                      ch=(char)(sum+64);
              }
              else
              {
                  ch=(char)(ch+num);
              }
              newStr=newStr+ch;
          }
          System.out.println("entered str : "+str+" num : "+num+" newstr : "+newStr);
   }
}
```

Comment: output: Input a string
ABCXYZ
input a number
3
entered str : ABCXYZ num : 3 newstr : DEFABC

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the input as a string and then convert to a char array

```
String str = br.readLine();
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

Comment: I agree with this. You could use a foreach-loop then.

Answer (score 2):

The new functional and a more concise style of getting the complete string would be

Try /catch block has been ommitted.
You can call this method and read through each character in a traditional way(using String.tocharArray())on a given returned string, even if you need to read through each character. This method returns the complete string.

```
   public String getValue(){

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        return br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing

```
System.out.println("input a number");
char a=char.parseChar(br.readLine(System.in));
```

Try this for getting single character

```
System.out.println("input a number");
String abc=br.readLine(System.in);
char a=abc.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert a `String` to a `char`, because a string contains multiple chars.  If you were expecting to get the first character of the string, then you need to use `charAt` method.  Make sure to check for string length first, or you'll get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
String str = br.readLine(System.in);
char a = str.length() > 0 ? str.charAt(0) : '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void encodeDecode() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Input a string");
    //Get a char array from String input.
    char[] chars = br.readLine().toCharArray();


    System.out.println("input a number");
    //Read increment as String and convert to int
    int increment = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()  );

    for (char c : chars) {
        System.out.println((char)((c + increment > 90) ?((90 - c)+65):c+increment));
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the number entered is 100 or anything above 26

Answer (score 0):

```
public class crypt {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String str;
        System.out.println("enter the string");
        str=br.readLine();
        String ustr=str.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("upper case string is");
        System.out.println(ustr);
        int l= ustr.length();
        System.out.println("enter the number");
        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()) ;


        for(int i=0; i<l ;i++)
        {
            char ch = ustr.charAt(i);

            int x= (int)ch;
            int y = x+n;
            if((y)>90)
            {
                int q=((y)%90);
                char h=(char)(64+q);
                System.out.print(h);

            }
            else
                System.out.print((char)y);


        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since `a` is an `Integer`, change it to:

```
 System.out.println("input a number");
 int a  =  Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Then:

```
 String res = "";//stores the result
      for (int x = 0; x < l; ++x) {
          char t = ustr.charAt(x);
              //check after adding the number, still is a letter
              // 35 is for 'Z'
          if(Character.getNumericValue(t) + a < 36)
              res += (char)(t + a);
          else{
              res += (char)(t + a - 26);
          }
      }
      System.out.println(res);
```